# How can I avoid writing many very similar setter methods?

Tags: java

I am working on a piece of code where the following applies:

1. I need to instanciate a lot of similar objects within an instance of Class A
2. Each of these objects will then get their own setter in Class B, which corresponds 1:1 to the objects created in the instance of Class A
   i.e. 
   In class A:

   ```
       B b = new B();

       final SomethingA somethingA1 = new SomethingA("input1");
       b.setSomethingA();

       ...
       final SomethingB somethingB15 = new SomethingB("input15");
       b.setSomethingB15();
       ...

       final SomethingA somethingA23 = new SomethingA("input23");
       b.setSomethingA23();
   ```

Where all "somethings" inherit from the same class.

3. The setter does nothing but:

   ```
   public void setSomethingX(somethingX){
   this.somethingX = somethingX; 
   }
   ```

I really do not want to write 23 setters that all do almost the same. Is there something like a multi-purpose setter?

The context of this is preparing an HTTP response in a very specific context and using some very specific frameworks. Apparently, this way of doing saves lot of work somewhere else (that I have no influence on). 
Also, as you can probably tell I am a novice developer.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the context, but why not use a `Map` of properties?

Comment: You can put everything in 1 method, but that is not the prupose of a setter method. Eclipse can auto-generate all setter methods for you

Comment: Nobody writes getters or setters anymore but rather let the respective IDE generate them ;)

Comment: A few options: (a) use your IDE to auto-generate them (b) use Lombok (c) use a different language (Kotlin comes to mind - you could even use Kotlin just for those POJOs and write the rest of your code in Java).

Comment: Why do you have 23 properties on a single class - that seems like a mess.

Comment: To broaden the subject: If your different child classes of X do respective special behaviour a better design would be to instead of let your class decide what to do on which object invent a abstract method on `X` which each class implements on their own. That would be much more OOP than procedural programming.

Comment: why use setters in the first place? If it's just a data-holder-object, you can make the fields `public` and assign the value directly. Or even better, make `B` immutable (all fields final + all values provided via the constructor)

Comment: Another option is to use a tool such as [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/) to automatically generate the mapping code.

Comment: use builder pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple technics to reduce setters:

1) Create constructor with B as parameter

```
class A {

    private B b;

    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }    
}  

A a = new A(new B());
```

2) Use builder pattern (with lombok will be easy to implement):

```
@Builder // lombok annotation
class A {
    private B b;
}

A a = A.builder().withB(b).build();
```

3) Use factory method:

```
class A {

    private B b;

    public static A newInstance(B b) {
        A a = new A();
        a.b = b;
        return a;
    }

}

A a = A.newInstance(new B());
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [Lombok setter/getter](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter) for this.

A single annotation that would trigger the creation of those methods. The source code in your IDE will not be polluted with those setters and a lot easier to read.

There is a [proposal](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/amber/datum.html) for data classes, but not yet implemented FYI.